# Can I change the length of list in a class?

Tags: python, list, class

Say if I define a class "Zillion",and I make the input as

```
m = Zillion([9,9,9,9,9,9])
```

And then I apply a method named "increment" defined in the Zillion Class. And I wish to get

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0].
```

The question is: I can get `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]` when I do `m.increment`. But if I repeat `m.increment`, the result becomes

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,0,0,2]
......
```

Seems like I can not change the length in the class. Can I?

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Comment: What you can or cannot do largely depends on the implementation of `Zillion.increment`..

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you should have realised that as soon as you stated you can get `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. So obviously the problem isn't *getting* the extra digit, it's *keeping* the extra digit.

Without seeing your code, we can't actually tell you what's wrong with it (with a degree of certainty) but you'll see you can both get *and* keep a longer list as per the code below. First, the obligatory initialisation:

```
class Zillion:
    # Init: simply set to zero.

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [0]
```

Now, the code to increment a number. It simlply uses the algorithms taught in any decent grade school:

```
    # Increment the number.

    def increment(self):
        # Force 1 to be added initially.

        carry = 1

        # Iterate over digits in reverse.

        for index in range(len(self.data) - 1,-1,-1):
            # Add current carry and set new carry based on result.

            self.data[index] = self.data[index] + carry
            if self.data[index] == 10:
                self.data[index] = 0
                carry = 1
            else:
                carry = 0

        # If carry at end then there was overflow, insert 1 at left.

        if carry == 1:
            self.data.insert(0,1)
```

Then just some test harness code so you can see it in action:

```
    # Code for debugging.

    def output(self):
        print self.data

# Test code here, show various increments.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = Zillion()

    for x in range(8): # -> 8
        z.increment()

    for x in range(13): # -> 21
        z.output()
        z.increment()
    z.output()

    print "==="
    for x in range(999977): # -> 999,998
        z.increment()

    for x in range(13): # -> 1,000,011
        z.output()
        z.increment()
    z.output()
```

Running that code gives you the confidence that the list changes in length and maintains itself correctly:

```
[8]
[9]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[1, 7]
[1, 8]
[1, 9]
[2, 0]
[2, 1]
===
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! But if my input is converted from a string. like m.Zillion = ('999 999 999') and it will give me the output as [9,9,9,9,9,9] and it is completed in the __init__ function. Then I apply increment method on [9,9,9,9,9,9]. Can I still change the length?

Comment: @Lily, no point _telling_ us what the code does, ask a question _showing_ us the code. The fact that you list is of by a factor of 1000 means that there are _other_ problems than just incrementing. In any case, you _can_ change the length as I've shown - whether the original data comes from a hardcoded `[0]` or a string is not relevant.

Comment: @paxdiabo,thanks for your explanation.I would like to paste my code there. But I am writing a code for my lab and my professor said that we'd better not post our code on the internet before we turn it in... So I am kind concern...

Comment: @Lily, that's fine. It just means we can't help you with your _specific_ problem very easily. I suspect you'll have to look over what we've provided then apply that knowledge to your own code (which is good from an education standpoint anyway).

Comment: @paxdiabo,If I paste my code,is it possible that I delete it after I solve the problem?

Comment: @Lily, if you're really paranoid about it, leave me a comment on some article over at http://powerfield-software.com/ with your email and I'll try help you out: _help,_ not do, remember that :-) No-one else will see the email address, comments have to be approved before publication so I'll be the only one getting it. Alternatively, you try on your own: important bit is that, once you have the number as a list belonging to the object (eg: `self.data`), you can do anything you want with that list, including inserting a `1` at the start.

Comment: I wouldn't go the post/delete route since that's really not what SO is for. It's a bit mean using their infrastructure for stuff that doesn't benefit the whole community :-)

Comment: @paxdiabo thanks so much!!I really appreciate it! Actually I don't mind letting other people know my email address. It's lilium798conan@gmail.com   Do you mind email me back? And I will show you my code.Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Zillion():
    def __init__(self, lst):
       self._lst = lst
    def increment(self):
       sum = int(''.join([str(z) for z in self._lst])) + 1
       self._lst = [int(z) for z in list(str(sum))]
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self._lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   z = Zillion([9,9,9,9,9,9])
   print 'Initially, z=%s' % z
   for i in range(11):
      z.increment()
      print 'Incremented, list is now = %s' % z


$ python x.py 
Initially, z=[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
Incremented, list is now = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```